# Typescript autoloading Cannot find module for some files

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, autoload

I am trying to get typescript to load my classes but I am running into errors, some do get loaded and others don't.

I added the following to **compilerOptions** in the **tsconfig.json** file.

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
    "igsys/*": [
        "src/igsys/*"
    ]
}
```

These are my imports

```
import { AuthController } from 'igsys/controllers/AuthController';
import { CredentialsInterface } from 'igsys/interfaces/CredentialsInterface';
import { Validator } from 'igsys/validation/Validator';
```

With the above imports CredentialsInterface (interface) does get imported correctly but for the AuthController (class) I get the following error

```
Cannot find module "igsys/controllers/AuthController"
```

This is my current directory structure of igsys directory

```
├── controllers
│   ├── AuthController.ts // -> class
│   └── controller.module.ts // -> class
├── interfaces
│   └── CredentialsInterface.ts // -> interface
└── validation
    ├── Rules.ts // -> class
    └── Validator.ts // -> class
```

Anybody knows what might be going on?

Also now that I am asking, is it also possible to be able to do imports like this:

```
import { AuthController } from 'igsys/controllers';
```

Comment: What happens when you add another interface (like the `CredentialsInterface`) to your imports. Will this throw an error too?

Comment: @Slence Another interface works fine.